# In the iptables i have a rule for ssh, why doesn't it work?

Tags: ssh, iptables

I have changed all the iptables chains to `DROP`, and made a rule to allow ssh from the computer (10.21.0.40, have hidden NAT, eth1) to Ubuntu Server (172.16.21.1, static ip, eth0), here is the rule:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -dport 22 -i eth1 -s 10.21.0.40 -d 172.16.21.1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

and when I'm trying to connect from the computer to the ubuntu server in ssh, I get the error:

```
connect to host 172.16.21.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

why that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule was fine, forgot to install open-ssh.

Comment: Then delete the question.

Comment: @StarOS no let's not, it helped me and others!

Answer (score 1):

The rule you quoted wouldn't work due to syntax errors. In addition to this, you had two other issues:

- you only allowed incoming connections that only have the SYN flag set (new connections)
- you set the default policy to DROP for OUTPUT chain without permitting replies to go out. How would the SSH server send its responses?

The complete set of rules to add on the machine which you want to accept incoming SSH connections:

```
# Flush all the rules in all tables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

# Delete all user defined tables
iptables -X

# Set default policies (you normally leave OUTPUT as 'ACCEPT')
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow local connections
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP traffic (optional)
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow TCP sessions that are already established
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Finally, allow incoming SSH connections.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: First of all the rule have no syntax error, iptables took it in, second, It's okay that the OUTPUT chain is drop, I have a rule that allow TCP sessions that are already established in INPUT, which means that it will respond back too (It is working, I already checked it). and a ssh connection start with a SYN, so how does that a problem ?

Comment: Yes but @Benny, you didn't say some of this important stuff in your original question. Please post your entire iptables rule set in your question, as we need the full context to be able to answer.